# Why after installing Chrome app, it fires on new tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I created a Chrome app you can try it here

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/style-scout/chbdclbnkfcocaolknbjmmppendkmebh

but after I install it and I open a new tap the app fires immediately and only for the very first time... why is that happening?

manifest is

```
{
    "background":
    {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "browser_action":
    {
        "default_icon": "icon-128.png",
        "default_title": "Style Scout"
    },
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",
    "name": "Style Scout",
    "short_name": "Style Scout – Fonts & Colors Finder",
    "description": "Fonts & Colors Finder",
    "homepage_url": "https://stylescout.org",
    "icons":
    {
        "16": "icon-16.png",
        "48": "icon-48.png",
        "128": "icon-128.png"
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "storage"],
    "version": "0.612",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["activate-np-chrome.js"]
    }],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["np-chrome.js"]
}
```

and **background.js**:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        file: "np-chrome.js"
    })
});
```

np-chrome.js is the actual full script of my app...

Comment: Why shouldn't it fire for every tab? You have `<all_urls>` in the `matches` option.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: @Barmar not sure if i was clear: after installing it, what happens to my browser is that the app is fired immediately on the tab the user open just after the installation... it should not. I mean it should only when you click the icon not earlier

Comment: What's in `activate-np-chrome.js`? It will be executed immediately whenever the page matches `<all_urls>`.

Answer (score 0):

ok I completely removed this part

```
  "content_scripts": [
{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["activate-np-chrome.js"]
}],
"web_accessible_resources": ["np-chrome.js"]
```

and now it works, because I didn't know that content_scripts actually inject and fire the script for every single tab ever, whereas i just needed to fire my script when the user clicks my browser button